# How-to get hierarchical categories that contains a least one product

Tags: c#

Assuming the following hierarichal parent/child category model :

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public IList<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
        public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get all categories in a hierarchical way that contains at least one product.

Root Category

a1. Sub Category 1 (0 product)

a2. Sub Category 2 (1 product)

b1. Sub Category 1 (0 product)

b2. Sub Category 2 (1 product)

b3. Sub Category 3 (0 product)

The expected result is :

Root Category

a1. Sub Category 1

a2. Sub Category 2

b1. Sub Category 1

b2. Sub Category 2

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to start from all products by getting their attached categories and tried to recurse from these to recreate the hierarchy. But dont succeed..

Comment: I suspect the reason you have 3 down votes and not many answers is because this looks like a "please write the code for me" type question. You will get more help if you edit your question with evidence that you have tried to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linq then this is simple. Something along the lines of:

```
var categoriesWithProducts = category.Where(x=> x.Products.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: I need to get the hierarchy, not all categories in à flatten manner

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
Category? GetNotEmpty(Category category)
{
   Category returnCategory = new Category();
   foreach(Category subCategory in category.ChildCategories)
          if(GetNotEmpty(subCategory) != null) returnCategory.ChildCategories.Add(GetNotEmpty(subCategory));

   if(returnCategory.ChildCategories.Count > 0 || returnCategory.Products.Count > 0) return returnCategory;
   else return null;
}
```

And call for all of the top categories.